# Pass a list of files to grep

Tags: grep

I have a list of files in a file. The list is huge, and the filenames are non-standard: that means, some have spaces, non-ascii characters, quotes, single quotes ...

So, passing that *huge* list of files to grep as arguments is not an option:

- because I am not sure that I will not exceed the length of the arguments allowed in linux. I guess I can solve this by partitioning arguments with `xargs`, though.
- because escaping those characters is complicated. If I want to enclose the filename in double quotes and that filename happens to have a double quote, I am in trouble. So I would need to escape some characters. The whole thing looks very complicated, and I do not want to walk that path.

There must be a simpler way: how can I tell grep to use my list of files as files to grep from? I assume that since the list of files would not be processed by the shell, escaping and argument length is not an issue anymore. The question is whether grep supports this operation mode, which I have been unable to find in the documentation.

Comment: Shouldn't something like this work to you? `while read file; do grep .... "$file" done < your_file_list` Note the `"$file"` to allow spaces in the file name.

Comment: Not sure what can happen if file has a double quote ... I know that is strange, but it is possible (the filesystem supports that)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GNU grep does not support this as far as I know. You have a few options.

**Use a bash loop to parse your file list**

This is the solution provided by @fedorqui

```
while read file; do 
    grep "$PATTERN" "$file" 
done < file_with_list_of_files
```

**Use xargs to pass multiple files to grep at once**

Here I've told xargs to pass 10 filenames to grep

```
PATTERN='^$' # searching for blank lines
xargs -n 10 -d '\n' grep "$PATTERN" < file_with_list_of_files
```

**Use xargs to pass multiple files to grep at once, dealing with newlines in filenames**

As above, but using null-terminated lines

```
PATTERN='^$' # searching for blank lines
tr '\n' '\0' file_with_list_of_files
xargs -n 10 -0 grep "$PATTERN" < file_with_list_of_files
```

**Edit:** deal with whitespace correctly
**Edit2:** Remove example that produces garbled output, add example that deals with newlines

Comment: Thanks! The first option is probably too slow (a new grep process for each file). The third can produce garbled output (several processes writing in parallel to stdout?). The second one is problably what I will use. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: One question: would xargs properly handle any file name, including filenames with unicode chars, or unexpected chars like double quote? What is the format expected by xargs? I assume one file per line. How to specify a filename with an embedded newline? (strange, but the filesystem allows for that)

Comment: I see now that `-d` specifies the delimiter. I have tested your approach with filenames with *very* strange characters, and it works perfectly (even for double quotes, single quotes, spaces, any unicode char, ...). The only thing I am unable to support is an embedded newline, since I do not know how to generate the list of files in that case (since the newline is put as-is in the lof, and then xargs assumes two different files). That corner case will stay unsupported.

Comment: xargs supports null-terminated strings using the -0 flag, if you null-terminate your list of filenames this will probably deal with the embedded newlines case. try `tr '\n' '\0' list_of_files` to get your input list in this format

Comment: Use `-H` flag with grep to prefix output with filename just like when -r is used.