# grep files with whitespaces in filename

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a list contains filenames. Some of filenames contain whitespaces:

```
./folder/folder/some file name.ext
```

I need to grep each of these files:

```
cat filelist | while read i; do grep "pattern" $i; done
```

Obviously grep fails because of whitespaces:

```
grep ./folder/folder/some: No such file or directory
grep file: No such file or directory
grep name: No such file or directory
```

I've tried to escape whitespaces like:

```
:%s/some file name/some\ file\ name/g
```

but no luck.
How can I perform my operation?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `\s` instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass a list of files to grep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793167/pass-a-list-of-files-to-grep)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote `$i`

```
cat filelist | while read i; do grep "pattern" "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this loop:

```
while read -r i; do grep "pattern" "$i"; done < filelist
```

Using a pipe with `cat` is error prone and BASH will treat strings with space as separate arguments.

Comment: I think using `cat` is not a problem. The problem itself is actually `$i` not being quoted with `""` causing it to have word splitting.

Answer (score 6):

Simpler if you use `xargs`:

```
xargs -d '\n' -- grep pattern -- < filelist
```

If you really need to have only 1 file processed per instance of `grep`, add `-n 1`:

```
xargs -n 1 -d '\n' -- grep pattern -- < filelist
```

You can also use `readarray`:

```
readarray -t files < filelist
for f in "${files[@]}"; do grep pattern -- "$f"; done
```

Or simply

```
readarray -t files < filelist
grep pattern -- "${files[@]}"
```

And make sure files are in UNIX format:

```
sed -i 's|\r||' filelist  ## Or
dos2unix filelist
```

Which you can do directly with process substitution:

```
readarray -t files < <(exec sed -e 's|\r||' filelist)
xargs -d '\n' -- grep pattern -- < <(exec sed -e 's|\r||' filelist)
```

Comment: What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @TomFenech The former is strictly following the method in which one file is processed per instance.

Comment: `xargs` pattern is much more efficient than `while` or `for` loops. Imagine you're grepping through a list of million files - every single file will be opened, read and closed using while/for loops. It took couple of hours for me to grep through 10% or even less of the list.
And with `xargs` I achieved more in a few minutes.

Comment: @kK-Storm Every single file will still be opened using xargs. The only difference (significantly) is that fewer instances of grep are executed - unless you add `-n 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Easy and effecient:

```
var=$(awk '{ print "\""$0"\""}' filelist)
command="grep \"pattern\" $var"
eval $command
```

Or if you wanted it as a one liner:

```
command="grep -ir \"pattern\" $(awk '{ print "\""$0"\""}' <<< "$(ls)")"; eval $command
```